# Blank space in mat-icon-button

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have created a mat-icon-button with an icon and without text and I expected it to only have the size of the icon. However, the button seems to have the size of the icon, plus an invisible white space on the right that I assume is for the text.

I tried to find solutions to make the whitespace disappear but none seem to work.
My button code in html :

```
<table id="tablePrevisions" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Modèle</th>
    <th scope="col">Domaine</th>
    <th scope="col">Emprise</th>
    <th scope="col">Echéances</th>
    <th scope="col" class="validation-col">Validation</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let previsionMeteo of previsionsMeteo; let i = index">
    <td (click)="onRowClicked(previsionMeteo)">{{ previsionMeteo.reseau }}</td>
    <td (click)="onRowClicked(previsionMeteo)">{{ previsionMeteo.cod_modele }}</td>
    <td (click)="onRowClicked(previsionMeteo)">{{ previsionMeteo.cod_domaine }}</td>
    <td (click)="onRowClicked(previsionMeteo)">{{ previsionMeteo.emprise }}</td>
    <td (click)="onRowClicked(previsionMeteo)">{{ previsionMeteo.echeances_plage }}</td>
    <td>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="showValidation(previsionMeteo)" [class]="classButtons[i]" [disabled]="classButtons[i]=='validation-not-exists'">
            <mat-icon>list_all</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And my classes in css :

```
.validation-exists {
    color: blue;
    width: 50px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.validation-not-exists {
    color: gray;
    width: 50px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

An illustration of the problem:

[image]

Comment: It may have something to do with using a table for your buttons. Does it have to be a table? You may use only a list, like <ul> and so on. Using tables for layout is a bad practice. Please show some more HTML, then I may be able to help.

Comment: I updated the HTML to add the whole table, we used table to show rows of data and each data might have a validation or not, which is why the buttons can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Thanks for showing the code. I will make a guess now: because you are using a table with content inside each <td> wider than your button at the end, the table will have the width of the widest text element, so your last <td> with the button inside, gets this width as well. Let me think about a solution...

Comment: I got rid of the class "validation-col" in the Validation column that was changing the width to 50px, and the column is now around the same width as the button. So I think you are correct about the <td> width but I can't find a way to set it properly.

Comment: Let me make a remark to my first comment about "using tables for layout is a bad practice": in this case using a table is perfect. With <thead> added for the titles is good for accessibility. I haven't seen the whole piece of HTML, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came back to this problem later, and tried with existing examples in Angular, and I discovered that the problem is actually much simpler. I just wrote mistakenly the name of the mat-icon as `list_all` (which I found on some website that I don't remember) instead of `list`, and when I wrote `list` it worked.

I don't know if it's made on purpose or not, but it seems that Angular uses only the beginning of the string to find the icon and if there is something written after, this effect happens.

I tried it with the icon for "home" and added something after like `home_test` and got the same effect. I don't think this bug is problematic in terms of security for Angular but this information might be useful for others who make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this here:

```
<td class="validation-button-table-data">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="showValidation(previsionMeteo)" [class]="classButtons[i]" [disabled]="classButtons[i]=='validation-not-exists'">
        <mat-icon>list_all</mat-icon>
    </button>
</td>
```

And then add your CSS to the `<td>` with the measurements instead of the button:

```
.validation-button-table-data {
    width: 50px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Let me know if that looks better then.

UPDATE:

Please have a try with adding the same CSS class `validation-button-table-data` with the measures to your last `<th>` as well. Like this:

```
<th scope="col" class="validation-button-table-data">Validation</th>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the result is the same, the width of the td changes to a smaller size, but the button stays at the same size, going outside of the column like the picture shows in the first post.

Comment: I have the same result with both td and th having this class. I should add that the button is clickable outside of the table, on the right. So it seems that the button component is bigger than the td component, which is why I tried changing the button width in the beginning.